# How do I accurately track mouse movement on a window?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Right now I am working on a way to update the state of an element based on whether the mouse is down as well as whether the mouse is over the element. This means that once the mouse is down, every time it hovers over one of the elements, the state changes. The tracking is inaccurate, it does not capture every single action. How do I improve the process?
The code for my present implmentation is:

```
document.onmousedown = () => {
      document.onmousemove = (e) => {
        if (e.buttons === 1) {
          let svg = e.target as HTMLElement;
          if (svg.id.startsWith('svg')) {
            let SVG_ID = svg.id;
            let HoverPropsID = svg.id.replace('svg', 'props');
            if (document.getElementById(HoverPropsID).classList.contains('no-node')) {
              toRemove.forEach(element => document.getElementById(SVG_ID).classList.remove(element));
              document.getElementById(SVG_ID).classList.add(`svg-${node}`);
              document.getElementById(HoverPropsID).classList.remove('no-node');
              document.getElementById(HoverPropsID).classList.add(node);
              multiNodeGraphUpdate(node, Number(HoverPropsID.substring(HoverPropsID.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)), 10, false)
            }
            nodeHoverAnimation(HoverPropsID);
          }
        }
      }
```

I understand that the information I have provided might be a big ambiguous, so I am linking two websites, one is the inspiration website: https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/

and the other one is the WiP webiste (my own): https://aarnavv.github.io/Vagus/

Comment: I think you should set a `state` changing whether the mouse is down or not, and a `hover` event on each of your tiles, checking the `state` and changing a property of the tile, because the way you did it is a bit messy.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 as in give a state of isMouseDown or something to its parent? and based on that give a onHover property to its children which gets fired only when the isMouseDown from the parent is true?

Comment: Exactly. I checked your code and saw you use in React, so this should be the way I would handle it.